# How do I add a URL to R markdown?

Tags: r, hyperlink, knitr, r-markdown

I want to refer a URL link to the R markdown and I already tried the input such as "addlink" 
or "address <- ...." 
Both of them do not work.
How can I add a link in R markdown?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** op's code from comment was

```
   {r} [linked phrase] (www.bit.ly/1EqAdIp)
```

Comment: Please add some code !!!

Comment: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_basics.html

Comment: I tried this one:[linked phrase] (http://bit.ly/1EqAdIp), but it's still not working :(

Comment: With a space between "]" and "("?

Comment: It says "Error: unexpected '[' in "["  "

Comment: Did u use lyx or just type that code into R markdown?

Comment: ```{r}
[linked phrase] (www.bit.ly/1EqAdIp)
```

Comment: Why do you keep putting a space between "]" and "("? It should be "](".

Comment: I delete the space but it's still not working...

Comment: As suggested by @Dev, pleas add code in your original post.

Answer (score 83):

Noting @Hao's answer below, that this must be in the main text, not within a code block:

From [this fabulous resource](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

```
[I'm an inline-style link](https://www.google.com)

[I'm an inline-style link with title](https://www.google.com "Google's Homepage")

[I'm a reference-style link][Arbitrary case-insensitive reference text]

[I'm a relative reference to a repository file](../blob/master/LICENSE)

[You can use numbers for reference-style link definitions][1]

Or leave it empty and use the [link text itself]

Some text to show that the reference links can follow later.

[arbitrary case-insensitive reference text]: https://www.mozilla.org
[1]: http://slashdot.org
[link text itself]: http://www.reddit.com
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using shiny, all you need to do is at the markup (white) area:

```
[linked phrase](www.bit.ly/1EqAdIp) #no space, no {r}
```

This way you enter the hyperlink at the text(=markup) and not the interactive portion(~R) of your page.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't put the hyperlink inside the R code block. xxx is the Markdown syntax. If you put it after `{r}`, knitr/rmarkdown will treat it as part of the R code and, of course, R will produce an error message.

Solution: remove `{r}`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code to add a url which represent the topic.

```
[ggrepel](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel)
```

That is:

```
[topic](url)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an internal link to your RMD, that is reference the appendix from the summary section, ex:

## summary

**link here to heading 2 of appendix section**

## appendix

### Heading 2 of Appendix

you would add the following (note this is case-sensitive, everything is now lower-case and spaces are exchanged with hyphens):

````
# summary

**[name of link](#heading-2-of-appendix)**

```{r}
```

# appendix

```{r}
```

## Heading 2 of Appendix
````

Also, note that in the reference to the heading-2-of-appendix, there is only one #, regardless of the type of heading the section-to-be-referenced is in.