# Add a hyperlink to a .R file (not R markdown file)

Tags: r, hyperlink

I would like to add clickable a hyperlink (e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm.plugin.factiva/index.html) to a .R file.

I found a solution for a R markdown files ([How do I add a URL to R markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787850/how-do-i-add-a-url-to-r-markdown)), however, I could not find a solution to enter hyperlinks directly into .R files.

I thought about to add a hyperlink as `#https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm.plugin.factiva/index.html`

Is there any other solution?

Comment: `.R` files are not generally interpreted in that manner, afaict. With R-markdown, for instance, most editors and rendering tools know what to do with `![alt text](https://...)`, but since R *source* is not typically displayed in a webpage sort of way, I don't think anything assumes to make anything url-like "clickable". Some editors likely do it, but it's completely on them to do the parsing and inference. (In which case ... just including the full URL might be sufficient.)

Comment: In an R script in RStudio on Windows I can open a hyperlink included in a comment with Shift + Mouse Click.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to document your R code with clickable hyperlinks (and formatted lists, typeset equations, etc.), I recommend [roxygen2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html).  [RStudio](https://posit.co/products/open-source/rstudio/) offers excellent workflow support for creating documentation for "oxygenated" R code.

However if your intent is to write a "self-documenting" .R file, then your idea (of including a URL in a comment) is fine.  The person who is reading your .R file will understand your intended reference even if you don't decorate your URL with the angle brackets or square brackets-and-parentheses that'd be required for it to be interpreted as a link in the document-compilation workflow for an oxygenated code.